# Poor Performance for Form Rendering In Django 1.11

Tags: html, django, forms, python-2.7, performance

[My site](https://www.morphmarket.com) has a navbar with an advanced search widget (beside the search field), which renders on every page.  For each request, a `context_processor` creates the form so it can be available on that page in the navbar.  This form has about a dozen selects with a total of several hundred options. Most of those options are for the currency and country selects, along with about 80 other options. There is an even larger list for "stores" but it is loaded via AJAX so it should not be a factor here.

Performance was fine on Django 1.8, but after upgrading to 1.11 (Pyton 2.7.15), I noticed with NewRelic that over 500 ms are now being used on my most frequent request between the following:

- Render/django/forms/widgets/select_option.html
- Render/django/forms/widgets/select.html
- Render/django/forms/widgets/attrs.html

[image]

This seems to be related to 1.11's change to [Template-based Widget Rendering](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/15667) ([docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/forms/renderers/#djangotemplates)), however the only pages I could find talking about related  problems were about Django Toolbar which I do not run in production.

I am and already using the Cached Template Loader (which is now default), however I don't know if this helps here.  I cannot easily cache this form because as you can see in the code, I set a number of defaults based on the request.

Why is my form suffering so badly from this change?  Eliminating two of the bigger selects helps, but surely several hundred options should not take this long to render so it seems to me there is an underlying problem that the quantity is merely exacerbating.

Here are links to to code for the full form and html. (I will include snippets in the question later when we identify the problem, for future readers).

- [Search Form](https://gist.github.com/jplehmann/b75379c12a37a6064f1face208d7dc88#file-search-py-L223)
- [Search HTML](https://gist.github.com/jplehmann/44872ab2c02da89080e9a199aed349ae)
- [Live Site](http://www.morphmarket.com)
- [Discussion on Mailing List](https://groups.google.com/forum/?#!msg/django-users/uhe7ExBJoxg/dYJgpY-VAgAJ)

### Update

Following this post, I disabled the largest of these selects and limped by for a year. This week I implemented a workaround so I could re-enable these options without paying the enormous cost.  I now cache the template fragment of the form, pass the selected form search options to the front end, and set them with JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

If you have truly isolated the widget rendering as the performance bottleneck, you can make your own widget for this with a different template.

```
class OptimizedSelectWidget(forms.Select):
    template_name = "widget_templates/optimized_select.html"

class MyForm(forms.Form):
    field = forms.ChoiceField(choices=XXX, widget=OptimizedSelectWidget)
```

The simpler you can make the template for `OptimizedSelectWidget`, the faster this will render.  The following is a general purpose (i.e. maximally complex) template for the select widget that supports the full functionality of the select widget.  I got this by taking the Django 2.2 dropdown template, and in-lining all of the children templates for options.

```
<select name="{{ widget.name }}"{% include "django/forms/widgets/attrs.html" %}>{% for group_name, group_choices, group_index in widget.optgroups %}{% if group_name %}
  <optgroup label="{{ group_name }}">{% endif %}{% for option in group_choices %}
  <option value="{{ option.value|stringformat:'s' }}" {% for name, value in option.attrs.items %}{% if value is not False %} {{ name }}{% if value is not True %}="{{ value|stringformat:'s' }}"{% endif %}{% endif %}{% endfor %}>{{ option.label }}</option>{% endfor %}{% if group_name %}
  </optgroup>{% endif %}{% endfor %}
</select>
```

I've tried this on a page where dropdown rendering was a performance issue and did get some speedup, but it was in the 20% range, not the 5x range.  My theory is that template caching is already doing a lot, so the templates themselves are not that high in overhead.  That said, this is on Django 2.2, which may have introduced some substantial performance improvements over 1.11.

The solution to this problem I ended up going with (the one that got me the 5x speedup) was to use Angular to move the rendering the dropdown options to the browser.  Frontend frameworks like Angular or React can be used just for rendering small parts of the page; you don't have to redo your whole frontend to be able to do this.

Comment: The timing of your answer is ironic given that I did not work on this issue in the past 11 months until last week right before you posted this, per my update. 20% probably would not have been enough, but I really appreciate you taking the time to share these ideas and hope they will be useful for someone.

Comment: @JohnLehmann Sounds like we came to the same conclusion: render the options with JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have past data of the same request, anything before the upgrade? If you are on the starter plan, maybe you only have 7 days of data: click on time-pick and set it to that date, then you can compare past info with current info to identify the bottlenecks.

Comment: Thanks, but I already know where slow down is and I detailed it above. The question at this point is more of a Django one, why did templates get so slow and what does one do to fix it.